# merge multiple timeseries of different length into a 2D matrix

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have an array of timestamps arrays where each timestamp array is of different length. For example,

```
[arr1, arr2, arr3....] 

arr1 = [0.24, 0.56, 0.77]
arr2 = [0.1, 0.24]
arr3 = [0.6, 0.7, 0.72, 0.88]
```

This is what the output should look like:

```
NaN, 0.24, 0.56, Nan, Nan,  Nan, 0.77, Nan
0.1, 0.24,  Nan, Nan, Nan,  Nan,  Nan, Nan
Nan,  Nan,  Nan, 0.6, 0.7, 0.72,  NaN, Nan
```

How do I go on to merge all of these arrays into a single 2D matrix? Another note is that each individual array `(arr1, arr2, ..)` are very large in size (tens of thousands).

I feel `pandas merge` function can be used but I don't know how to proceed with it.

Comment: you mean to flatten the array of arrays or do you want a 2D matrix?

Comment: merge into a 2D matrix

Comment: I can imagine several ways to interpret that.  I won't take the time to guess only to be wrong.  I'd rather you show us what you expect the 2D array should look like.

Comment: For example: a simple `pd.DataFrame([arr1, arr2, arr3])` does the trick.  Is that what you were looking for?  If not, then you see the problem of not explaining further.

Comment: @piRSquared I have edited to show what the output should look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with pandas:

```
arrs = [arr1,arr2,arr3]

# convert to series
series = [pd.Series(arr,index=arr) for arr in arrs]

# concat with reindex
pd.concat(series, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         0     1     2
0.10   NaN  0.10   NaN
0.24  0.24  0.24   NaN
0.56  0.56   NaN   NaN
0.60   NaN   NaN  0.60
0.70   NaN   NaN  0.70
0.72   NaN   NaN  0.72
0.77  0.77   NaN   NaN
0.88   NaN   NaN  0.88
```